# How to perform an action when Swipe Gesture Recogniser is used to go to another View in Swift

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, swipe, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

Here is my problem **(on Xcode 6.0.1, coding in Swift, using iOS 7.1 and 8.0)**: I am going from one view to another using a Swipe Gesture Recogniser (with the Action Segue "`present modally`").

Before this I was using a button "`next`" to go from one view to another. I created an `@IBAction` for this button next that was performing, let say, a simple `println("test")`.

```
@IBAction func nextPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("test")
}
```

If I run my app, when I press the button Next, I go to the next view  and "`test`" appears in the consol.

Now I do the same for a Swipe Gesture Recogniser, let say I create an `@IBAction` for the Swipe Gesture Recogniser (so I ctrl-click on the gesture icon next to the view controller icon at the top of the view, then drag into the code).

```
@IBAction func swipeGestureDone(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("test")
}
```

If I run my app, when I swipe on the screen, I go to the next view but the "**test**" does not appear in the consol. I cannot figure out how to execute a function when I use a Swipe to go from one view to another. It is apparently because there is no "**Sent Events**" for a Swipe Gesture Recogniser as for a Button. I don't know how to do it. Everything seems to be well connected in the Connection inspector though.

Answer (score 0):

Set `cancelsTouchesInView` of the recognizer to `true`. It does what it says.

Comment: I tried to do it in the code with `mySwipeGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = true` and also in the Attribute Inspector but it apparently doesn't change. I still don't have my **"test"** printing in the consol.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with a UITapGestureRecognizer. Here are a couple of things I found as solutions. They have not worked in my case, but maybe they will fix your issue:

Try selecting the type of object a UISwipeGestureRecognizer instead of AnyObject.

```
@IBAction func swipeGestureDone(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    println("test")  
}
```

Also make sure that your view recognises gestures by adding

```
yourView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```